# How does `cosine` metric works in sklearn's clustering algorithoms?

Tags: scikit-learn, metrics, dbscan

**I'm puzzeled about how does `cosine` metric works in sklearn's clustering algorithoms.**

For example, **DBSCAN** has a parameter `eps` and it specified maximum distance when clustering. However, bigger cosine similarity means two vectors are closer, which is just the opposite to our `distance` concept.

I found that there are `cosine_similarity` and `cosine_distance`( just `1-cos()` ) in pairwise_metric, and when we specified the metric is `cosine` we use `cosine_similarity`.

So, when clustering,  how does DBSCAN compares the cosine_similarity and @param `eps` to decide whether two vectors have the same label?

An example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

samples = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]]

clf = DBSCAN(metric='cosine', eps=0.1)

result = clf.fit_predict(samples)

print(result)
```

it outputs [-1, -1, -1, -1] which means these four points are in the same cluster

However,

- for points pair `[1,1], [2, 2]`,

  1. its cosine_similarity is 4/(4) = 1,
  2. the cosine distance will be 1-1 = 0, so they are in the same cluster
- for points pair`[1,1], [1,0]`,

  1. its cosine_similarity is 1/sqrt(2),
  2. the cosine distance will be 1-1/sqrt(2) = 0.29289321881345254, this distance is bigger than our `eps` 0.1, why DBSCAN clustered them into the same cluster?

Thanks for @Stanislas Morbieu 's answer, and I finally understand the `cosine` metric means `cosine_distance` which is `1-cosine`

Comment: And how should i tune my `eps` param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of DBSCAN in scikit-learn rely on [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors) (see the [implementation of DBSCAN](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py#L167)).

Here is an example to see how it works with cosine metric:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

samples = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
neigh = NearestNeighbors(radius=0.1, metric='cosine')
neigh.fit(samples) 

rng = neigh.radius_neighbors([[1, 1]])
print([samples[i] for i in rng[1][0]])
```

It outputs `[[1, 1], [2, 2]]`, i.e. the points which are closest to `[1, 1]` in a radius of `0.1`.

So points which have a cosine distance smaller than `eps` in DBSCAN tend to be in the same cluster.

The parameter `min_samples` of DBSCAN plays an important role. Since by default, it is set to `5`, no points can be considered as core point.
Setting it to `1`, the example code:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

samples = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]]

clf = DBSCAN(metric='cosine', eps=0.1, min_samples=1)

result = clf.fit_predict(samples)

print(result)
```

outputs `[0 1 2 2]` which means that [1, 1] and [2, 2] are in the same cluster (numbered 2).

By the way, the output `[-1, -1, -1, -1]` doesn't mean that points are in the same cluster, but that all points are in no cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have added some new info into my issue for readability

Comment: I updated my answer according to the example you added.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ignored this param and now I understand the actual metric is `cosine_distance(1-cosine)`.